# Regex pattern to find the occurrence of a pattern

Tags: java, regex

### Edit 1:

Please don't go by the example in a literal way. The key values can be of any string. Need not include "key" and "col" in them.

For example, the string can be the following

```
Ravi,India,Married;John,Canada,Single;Robert,Spain,Unknown
```

So, if I pass `Ravi` as the key, I should get `India` and `Married` as the result.

---

I am trying to use the Java regex pattern to find the details from a given string. The structure of the string is as follows:

```
Key1,Key1Col1,Key1Col2;Key2,Key2Col1,Key3Col2;Key3,Key3Col1,Key3Col2
```

where ; is the delimiter for each record.

My requirement is to accept the Key (which is `Key1, Key2` etc.) and return the corresponding values like `Key1Col1,Key1Col2` etc.

Comment: And you HAVE to use regex for this? You can't just split the string by `;` -> find which one starts with `key` -> split that one by `,`?

Comment: @VLAZ, yes the requirement is to do it by regex. Cannot use the Java code

Comment: You still kind of have to use Java code, because you need to build the regex from the input you get.

Comment: All I could do is to pass the regex pattern so that the processing happens in the backend

Comment: I'm confused now - do you have to generate the pattern that will match your thing *elsewhere* or the generate the pattern and use it to extract the data? Because these can lead to different code and different regexes in the end.

Comment: What is your result then? Array, list, string? What is the Java code that is going to extract this result? Only regex and related classes (Matcher, etc)? Or can you just extract the sub-sequence and split it?

Comment: You need to be more specific with exactly how the regex needs to be used. If I am understanding it correctly, you want to have it find all matches of the regex and no extra processing of the matches is allowed such as getting their groups or splitting them. Well, too bad Java doesn't allow infinite width lookbehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do it:

```
(?<=^Ravi,|;Ravi,)[^;]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/Tcmzhd/1

The link above shows PHP but it should work in Java no problem.

Comment: This gets values for two different keys.

Comment: @VLAZ OP specified that they want two different keys. They should consider editing the question so that I don't have to guess at the details.

Comment: @VLAZ So if `Key2` is given then precisely what should be the result?

Comment: My question? Also, the question already says that it has to take a key and do something with it to get the values.

Comment: @VLAZ Just realized you're not OP. Their question is hazy at best, misleading at worst.

Comment: As for what I expect...I have no actual idea - I'm very confused what the outcome of this should even be - a regex or some code that extracts data or what.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, added an example to the question. Please see if that makes it any better  than worst

Comment: @Ravi I see. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, this is exactly what I'm looking for. This works, Thanks